# LinqToSql Calculated Field OnPropertyIDChanged

Tags: linq-to-sql, partials, calculated-columns

I have a partial class to extend one of my LinqToSql classes.  In this partial class I have the following calculated field.

```
    public bool IsInCluster
    {
        get
        {
            return Cluster != null;
        }
    }
```

In order for a grid column databound to this field to update automatically I have implemented the following partial method.

> ```
>     partial void OnClusterIDChanged()
>     {
>         SendPropertyChanged("IsInCluster");
>     }
> ```

However when I update the Cluster property as shown in the following code the OnClusterIDChanged method does not get called:

> private void ExecCreateClusterCommand()
>   {
>
> ```
>         var cluster = new Cluster()
>         {
>             ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
>             MailService = AppState.CurrentMailService
>         };
>
>         App.DataContext.Clusters.InsertOnSubmit(cluster);
>
>         foreach (DeliveryPoint deliveryPoint in SelectedDeliveryPoints)
>         {
>             deliveryPoint.Cluster = cluster;
>         }
>
>         App.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
> ```
>
> }

I have successfully used this technique with other non navigation properties related to calculated fields.  Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find for this was to create a public method in the DeliveryPoint class enabling me to call SendPropertyChanged for the required field (navigation property):

```
        public void CallSendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            SendPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setter for `Cluster`, call `OnClusterIDChanged`, if the state has changed.

Comment: In my LinqToSQL generated classes there is no extensibility method for the setter for Cluster - only for OnClusterIDChanged.